# Linking to a homepage when Drupal is located in a Directory

Tags: theming

I have a problem with creating a proper link to the homepage of my website. I would like this code to redirect to my homepage:

```
<a href="/">
<div class="logo_wut">
<img style="display:inline;" src="photos/logoWUT_czarne.PNG" width="370" height="135">
</div>
```

Unfortunetaly it doesn't work, because it brings me to the homepage of my whole server and drupal is located in a subdirectory of the server. I tried to do this using php:

```
<a href="<?php print ('<front>');?>">
<div class="logo_wut">
<img style="display:inline;" src="photos/logoWUT_czarne.PNG" width="370" height="135">
</div>
```

but it doesn't work too. When i click on the image it appears:

> Page not found The requested page
>   "/drupal7/drupal-7.23/en/%3C?php%20print%20(%27%3Cfront%3E%27);?%3E"
>   could not be found.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`url()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7) function to generate a page URL. For the `frontpage` it is:

```
<a href="<?php print url('<front>'); ?>">YOUR LINK</a>
```

If the generated links using the url() function are not correct, you can change the `$base_url` variable in the `settings.php`

```
$base_url = 'http://www.yourwebsite.com/drupal7/drupal-7.23';
```

Comment: Unfortunetaly, this solution doesn't work either.

Comment: That's odd, Drupal should handle the url generation depending the site folder structure. I've added another solution by setting a `$base_url`

Answer (score 2):

There is global variable `$base_path` which define base URL path of the Drupal Installation.

This will at least default to '/'.

```
<?php global $base_path; ?>

<a href="<?php print $base_path; ?>">Home</a>
```

Or you can use `base_path()` function which will return the global variable `$base_path`.

```
<?php $path = base_path(); ?>

<a href="<?php print $path; ?>">Home</a>
```

Or, You can also define `$base_url` in your settings.php file of Drupal installation as below.

`$base_url = 'http://www.example.com';`

There should not be trailing slash (/) in your base url.

```
<?php global $base_url; ?>

<a href="<?php print $base_url; ?>">Home</a>
```

Kindly see that if you modify your `$base_url` in your `settigns.php` file, then you need to modify your `$base_url` when you transfer your file from development server to live server.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal stores the homepage URL in the $base_url global.

```
<a href="<?php global $base_url; print $base_url; ?>">YOUR LINK</a>
```

Details: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/base_url/7